# Does quantum mechanics allows absolute energies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, conventions, vacuum, hamiltonian

When we solve Schrödinger equation:

$$H\Psi=E\Psi$$

for a system, is $E$ an absolute energy? I mean, an energy that is not a difference between states.

Does this equation implies something about absolute or non-absolute entropy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the Hamiltonian operator contains a potential energy $V$:

$$ \hat{H} = \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 + V $$

and the potential energy isn't an absolute energy because we are free to set the zero of the potential energy wherever we want. So the energy in your equation is not an absolute energy but depends on where we take the zero for the potential energy.

Comment: Very nice answer..And zero is usually separated atoms? So, absolute energy is something without mean. But what about entropy? As far as I know all information of the system is on the equation..

Comment: If V were Zero, also kinetic energy is relative, isnt it?

Comment: Zero is not separated atoms. It is zero. And the equation does not have all the information because it excludes aether drag/ "zero point energy" or whatever it is called in relativity. And yes the kinetic energy is relative.

Comment: So physics doesn't say anything about the world, as maths..forget about relativity..@user41826

Comment: Well it depends on the physics